# How to get logged in user's email in Flutter using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to get the email of the logged in user in a Flutter app which uses Firebase for authentication.

I can get the current user by

```
final user = await _auth.currentUser();
```

But if I try this to get the mail

```
final mailID = await _auth.currentUser().email.toString();
```

I get the following error:

```
The getter 'email' isn't defined for the type 'Future<FirebaseUser>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'email', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'email'.
```

How to get the logged in user's email in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the user before trying to get the email. code below

```dart
<FirebaseUser> user = await _auth.currentUser();
final mailID = user.email;
```

Comment: Thank you, but any explanation as to why this happens? I mean why not in one command?

Comment: Ohh yea.
You have to `await` `_auth.currentUser()` but if you write it in one line you're just trying to get the email from a `Future`

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


FirebaseAuth.instance
    .authStateChanges()
    .listen((User? user) {
  if (user == null) {
    print('User is currently signed out!');
  } else {
    print('User is signed in!');
  }
 });
```